# Determine if paths exists and proceed in a clean way

Tags: powershell

I recently had to write a Powershell script that looked like this(Not actual script, this is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) :

```
function verify_file{
    param([string]$path_to_file)
    return Test-Path ($path_to_file)
}

$source_file = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Images"
$destination_file = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\ISO"

if ((verify_file -path_to_file $source_file) -and
    (verify_file -path_to_file $destination_file)){
    Write-Output("Good to go")
}else{
    Write-Output("We have trouble")
}
```

Problem is, it looks messy and you can't specifically state which directory is missing. If I need to verify another path I would then need to add to the `if` statement which can be frustrating.

While researching, I came across these two pages ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122485/elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else/122508#122508),[2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206816/clarification-of-avoid-if-else-advice?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and agreed with what was being said, so I refactored my code to look like this:

```
$process_paths = @{}
$process_paths.Add("Images",$source_file)
$process_paths.Add("Destination",$destination_file)
$toProceed = $true

foreach($varPath in $process_paths.GetEnumerator()){

    verify_file -path_to_file $varPath.Value

    if((verify_file -path_to_file $varPath) -eq $false){

        # Yes, I know using the "+" is bad, but see the bigger picture :D
        Write-Output ($varPath.Name + " doesn't exist")
        $toProceed = $false
    }
}

if($toProceed){

    # ops with the variables
}
```

I like this approach, if I had another path to verify, I simply add it to the hashtable, and let the loop take care of it. No need to add another `if` statement, and I can specify exactly which directory is missing.

All was well and good, until today, when I came across this [page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364418/setting-flag-in-a-loop-to-use-it-later-a-code-smell). It states that using a flag the way I did, can be a design smell. Problem is I'm unsure of how to restructure my code.

How would I restructure my code so that:

1. I can clearly tell the user which directories are missing
2. Should one or more directory be missing, we cannot proceed

Comment: What is the point of the `verify_file` function? It does the same thing and returns the same result as `Test-Path` (with reduced functionality), so what is the utility of it?

Comment: @briantist - Its just part of the mvce, the actually method is a lot longer and returns a `boolean` but it illustrates my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this:

```
function Test-PathEx {
  param(
    [String[]] $path
  )
  foreach ( $pathItem in $path ) {
    if ( -not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $pathItem) ) {
      return $pathItem
    }
  }
}

$missing = Test-PathEx "A","B","C"
if ( $missing ) {
  throw "Path does not exist - '$missing'"
}
```

Note that `Test-Path` also returns `$true` for paths that aren't specifically directories, so if that's really important, you would have to check the path type in the function.

Comment: I'd add `return` after the `throw` statement, otherwise very elegant, I like

Comment: Suppose if I wanted to continue with my second approach, would using the `boolean` the way I did cause a the problem specified in the link?